# changing genesis_before_while in new theme framework

Tags: hooks, actions, genesis-theme-framework

I am moving a site from a Genesis theme to Colorlib theme. The genesis theme includes `add_action( 'genesis_before_while', 'custom function' );`  in a custom archive page, which loads restricted content from a template part.  Is there a standard WP hook equivalent? or a work-around?

Comment: if there is there's no guarantee the Colorlib theme implements it, what/when exactly does `genesis_before_while` run?

Comment: ```Before the Loop Hook - genesis_before_while```  it goes above ```while_posts```

Comment: Here a comment about the hook ```The genesis_before_while runs after the if( have_posts() )
 * and before while( have_posts() ) : the_post();```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there's an equivalent filter in the new theme but there is no standard general hook you can use that acts as a direct replacement like for like.

You should check the Colorlib themes documentation and support, but keep in mind Genesis relies *heavily* on custom hooks by design, much more so than other themes. You might be able to manually add a hook in a child theme if Colorlib is built properly.

Comment: Thanks. I sent this question to the Colorlib folks..  I may need to recreate the whole query to fit the new theme.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking through Tom Nowell's advice it occurred to me I could create a custom hook and place it after `if( have_posts()`. This worked like a charm. Thanks again.  https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/custom-hooks/

Comment: note that this will be lost when you apply updates to the Colorlib theme

Comment: Yes.  I turned off auto updates on the theme. It is buying me much-needed time to develop a new query, so this works.